# how to use pointer change array element

Tags: c++

i try use pointer to change array element,but i fail.
it has not changed
how can i do?

i try some example like ** or &*
I am not good at C/C++,i don't know where I am wrong.
This is a matrix
B[0] is x
B[1] is y

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
int rotate(int A[10][10],int *PointerX,int *PointerY){
    int x = *PointerX;
    int y = *PointerY;
    printf("into rotate\n");
    printf("B:[%d][%d]",x,y);
    int B[10][10];
    initialize(B);
    for(int i=0,m=x-1;i<=x;i++,m--){
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
            B[j][m] = A[i][j];
            if(i==x&&j==y-1){
                x = j+2;
                y = i-1;
                printf("\nA:[%d][%d]\n",x,y);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            A[i][j] = B[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int ScanData(int A[10][10],int operate[10000],int B[3]){
    printf("DATA:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&B[0],&B[1],&B[2]);
    for(int i=0;i<B[0];i++){
        for(int j=0;j<B[1];j++){
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<B[2];i++){
        scanf("%d",&operate[i]);
    }
    return B[2];
}
int main(){
    int A[10][10];
    initialize(A);
    int operate[10000];
    int B[3];
    int operating = ScanData(A,operate,B);
    for(int i=0;i<operating;i++){
        if(operate[i]==0){
            rotate(A,&B[0],&B[1]);
        }else if(operate[i]==1){
            flip(A,B[0],B[1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i hope function rotate can change B[0] and B[1]
but isn't

Comment: Please comment your code to explain what it attempting to do where.

Comment: Are you saying that you want `main()`'s call to the `rotate()` function to change the values stored in `main()`'s `B[0]` and `B[1]`?

Comment: @熊振凱 It is not a C -code. There are no such headers as for example cstdio or cstring in C.

Comment: You probably just need to add `*PointerX = x;` `*PointerY = y;` before the `return 0;`.

Comment: @熊振凱 And where is there the function initialize?

Comment: @John Bollinger yes

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow 
it is Cpp
Maybe I misled what caused it to be labeled C

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow initialize just set all B array element to zero

Otherwise, the memory residual value will appear.

Comment: @lan Abbott 
Thanks for your suggestion,but it didn't improve
Maybe I should not change the value in this way?

Comment: @Scott Hunter I will pay attention next time.
it looks like cannot change after sending
Sorry to be your trouble

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
int x = *PointerX;
int y = *PointerY;
```

The variables `x` and `y` contain the *current* value of `B[0]` and `B[1]`.  They are not pointers, so when you later assign to `x` and `y` you're only assigning to the copies.

Remove `x` and `y` and replace them with `*PointerX` and `*PointerY`.

```
for(int i=0,m=*PointerX-1;i<=*PointerX;i++,m--){
    for(int j=0;j<*PointerY;j++){
        B[j][m] = A[i][j];
        if(i==*PointerX&&j==*PointerY-1){
            *PointerX = j+2;
            *PointerY = i-1;
            printf("\nA:[%d][%d]\n",*PointerX,*PointerY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer very much , but it still not change.
I'm not sure if it is related to Cpp.
i use <cstdio>,<cstdlib>,<cstring>